# PAYPAL currency is not working

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm using PHP to payment using Paypal
It's a shoping cart system.
Everything went fine for 6 months. Now we want to implement multiple currency facility in it. So I implemented one paypal variable called

```
currency_ code :: EUR
```

now I should be able to use EUR in place of USD. But when paying variable passes but Paypal uses USD not EUR. That means the price is in Dollar not Euro. What's the error?

Any idea why is this?

```
$invoice= $this->session->userdata('invoice');
$money= $this->session->userdata('tk');
$desc= $this->session->userdata('desc');

$store_owner= $this->session->userdata('store_owner');

$this->paypal_class->add_field('upload', '1');          
$this->paypal_class->add_field('business', $store_owner);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('return', $this->session->userdata('success'));
$this->paypal_class->add_field('cancel_return', $this->session->userdata('store'));
$this->paypal_class->add_field('notify_url', base_url().'ipn/index');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('invoice',$invoice);

$this->paypal_class->add_field('currency_ code', $this->session->userdata ('currency'));

$t = 1;
foreach ($cart as $c)
{
$this->paypal_class->add_field('item_name_'.$i, $c['product_name']);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('item_number_'.$i, $c['option_id']);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('on0_'.$i, 'Option');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('os0_'.$i, $c['option_name']);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('quantity_'.$i, $c['option_quantity']);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('amount_'.$i, $c['option_price']);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('shipping_'.$i, $c['option_shipping']);
$i++;
}

$this->paypal_class->add_field('discount_amount_cart', 5);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('tax_cart', 7.5);

$this->paypal_class->submit_paypal_post();
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, you use [add to cart button](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_shoppingcart-intro-outside)
To set currency you should use this code

`<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">`

Is it so in your button?

Could you post hole code of your button?

Comment: i am using it from my website
not using button

Comment: Ruslan, I see this code when it goes to paypal(by debugging) but it just not works

Comment: @Mazhar Ahmed: `$this->paypal_class->add_field('currency_ code', $this->session->userdata ('currency'));` You have error in your code: field name `'currency_ code'` should be without space, just like this `'currency_code'`

Comment: ohhhh, ooohhh sweeet, ohhhh, sweeet
it worked just fine. jajakALLAH (thanks a lot really big)